# removing one pixel "border-radius" from button link

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when I try to use `overflow: hidden;` to hide a background effect on a button. I see one pixel around of `border-radius` in Chrome:

[image]

What can I do to hide these pixels? I can try to use `box-shadow`, but maybe you know an easier way.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqyv2ypm/2/)

```
<a href="#" class="btn hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">test</a>
```

Css:

```
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0913a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden; /* <-- I try hide background but always get http://screencast.com/t/qktgZwmVtH */
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  background: #181818;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f0913a;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use an inset shadow:

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0913a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #f0913a;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #181818;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150px #181818;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">test</a>
```

it doesn't eradicate the bug , but the black is not there bleeding anymore.

---

**to avoid the bug**, Use another method, you may use a background-image such as a css gradient and resize it on hover (no pseudo involved either). example:[image]

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0913a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) left no-repeat, linear-gradient(black, black) right no-repeat #f0913a;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.3s;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">test</a>
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add `background-clip:padding-box;` on class `.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal`

**CSS:**

```
 .btn {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0913a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  background: #181818;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
    /* Prevent background color leak outs */
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
  -moz-background-clip:    padding; 
  background-clip:         padding-box;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f0913a;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

Demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/wd9exfmx/9/

Answer (score 0):

remove the overflow:hidden from the .btn class and change the left, right properties for the :before element, also set the border-radius to inherit for the :before element check the fiddle here for eg https://jsfiddle.net/0ap4qbrn/

```
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0913a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  background: #181818;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -2px;/*equal to the border width of .btn but negated*/
  right: -2px;/*equal to the border width of .btn but negated*/
  background: #f0913a;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:active:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-in-horizontal:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

give box-sizing:border-box; with webkit and moz prefix this may solve your issue